# How do you calculate the certainty of a probabilistic system?

Tags: probability

By probabilistic, I mean, of course, probability. By system, I mean an event which encompasses the input, process, and output. For example, with the flip of a coin, the input is head and tails, the output is heads or tails, the process is everything that happens in between, that causal chain leading to heads or tails such as the number of rotations, wind resistance etc.

Ok, so what I mean by certainty is best described by way of example. If you flip a coin, with a 50/50 chance of heads or tails, then you know the P of each outcome, individually. However, as a whole, you are 0% certain on what the outcome will be. If the coin is fixed, so that there is a 75% chance of heads, your are 'somewhat' certain, but not completely. If it's a 99% chance, you're virtually guaranteed a heads. If it's a 100% chance (say you filmed the flip, and followed that casual chain reaction), it is unambiguous, it *will* be heads, no questions asked.

As the probability that one event increases or decreases then, the certainty also increases. However, how do you calculate this certainty? Intuitively, you can get an idea of how certain you are based on the probability of the outcome from the set of mutually exclusive events, but how can you turn this intuition into cold hard mathematics?

Comment: You want a single number that describes the variability of a quantity? This would be something like a standard deviation, although I suspect that to you the variability of one quantity that is $0$ 50% of the time and $1$ 50% of the time would be the same as the variability of another quantity that is $0$ 50% of the time and $2$ 50% of the time.

Comment: Yes, I think I'd deem this as having the same variability. I'd certainty deem it as having the same certainty (wow, that's meta), but am not exactly sure how variability would be precisely defined in this case. If it's dependent upon the actual values (0 or 1 50% of the time vs 0 or 2 50% of the time), then no. Anyway, I'll look into standard deviation and see if it's what am looking for. Thanks :)

Comment: If those two cases are the same to you then no, standard deviation is not what you want. Maybe entropy (in the sense of probability, not thermodynamics) is what you want?

Comment: I have no idea, maybe. It looks interesting though.

Comment: [Coefficient of variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation)?  Although based on what you said—"dependent upon the actual values"—entropy seems like a good bet.